# Engine coolant help

Tags: engine, coolant, skoda

Hey I had water on expansion tank as ran out for coolant I have add pre mixed coolant and it sunk to the bottom and is  separated  from the water that was already existing in the expansion tank  is this okay

Answer (score 0):

Yeah of course, now you should be running just coolant through your system but having both wont kill it. What is happening is that the premix is denser then just water that's in there so it went to the bottom (will mix together after getting pulled into the system). Would recommend flushing the system and running just coolant though.